# Access caller object when using composition in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, composition

In ActionScript3, I am trying to access the properties of the caller object from a composite.

```
public class Robot {
 ...
 private var controlPanel:ControlPanel;
 ...
 public function Robot() {
 ...
 cPanel = new ControlPanel();
 ...
  }
 }
```

My ControlPanel needs to access properties from Robot instance, but I don't think I can pass `this` when calling the ControlPanel...

```
public class ControlPanel{
...
 public function ControlPanel() {
  //How can I refer back to robot properties ?
  //
 }
```

}

I believe I am in the case of composition as a Robot *has a* ControlPanel. I am thinking of using events, but there are many properties I need to access.

What would be the best way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always just let `ControlPanel` store a reference to its own `Robot` object, like so:

```
// ControlPanel
private var robot:Robot;

public function ControlPanel(robot:Robot) {
    this.robot = robot;
}
```

And then, when creating the control panel:

```
// Robot
public function Robot() {
    controlPanel = new ControlPanel(this);
}
```

Alternatively, you could create an even system of sorts, and then let the control panel dispatch them. You could create your own `ControlPanelEvent` class, and then let the Robot itself handle the results. For example, let's say you change a property called `foo` in the control panel. You could dispatch it like this:

```
var event:ControlPanelEvent = new ControlPanelEvent(ControlPanelEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, "foo", value);
```

Then you'd receive it like this:

```
public function Robot() {
    controlPanel = new ControlPanel();
    controlPanel.addEventListener(ControlPanelEvent.PROPERTY_CHANGE, updateProperty);
}

public function updateProperty(event:ControlPanelEvent):void {
    if (event.key == "foo") {
        this.foo = event.value;
    }
}
```

However, that's wordy and unnecessary. You could also use ActionScript's array access notation in the event handler, which would be a simple one-liner:

```
this[event.key] = event.value;
```

Still, that's not entirely secure, since you might not want the control panel to be able to update all of a robot's properties. Instead, you could maintain a simple map of configurable properties that the robot can have, and update that instead:

```
private var configuration:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

public function Robot() {
    // ...
    configuration.foo = "bar";
    configuration.baz = "qux";
    //...
}

public function updateProperty(event:ControlPanelEvent):void {
    if (configuration.hasOwnProperty(event.key))
        configuration[event.key] = event.value;
}
```

There you go. Of course, you *could* always just store the configuration map in the `ControlPanel` itself, and let the `Robot` pull from that, but if you absolutely need it as a property of the robot, here are a few solutions.

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I went with the first option, referencing robot within the ControlPanel.  I just wonder what happens if I call robot.controlPanel property from within the controlPanel itself ? it seems recursive... I will need to try it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass 'this':

```
cPanel=new ControlPanel(this);

public class ControlPanel{
    ...
    protected var _robot:Robot;
    public function ControlPanel(robot:Robot){
        _robot = robot;
    }
}
```

You can't use arguments when extending display classes, but ControlPanel extends Object (by default as no extend is defined.

For display classes you can set the property after creating it:

```
cPanel=new ControlPanel();
cPanel.robot = this;

public class ControlPanel{
    ...
    public var robot:Robot;
    public function ControlPanel(){
    }
}
```